# USB 3.0 Backpanel ports not working - Front Panel works Renesas 0.96

Tags: windows, usb, motherboard, usb-3, windows-10-v1703

I've got a [Asus P8Z68-deluxe Motherboard running version 3304](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z68_DELUXE/HelpDesk_Download/).

Now I have some issues with my USB3 ports, they don't work. The Renesas USB Controller starts showing yellow marks at the device when plugged in.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/3a32170e0ba5ee5f264d42c73611fb3e.png]

Clicking the device tells me the device has stopped because of some errors (Code 43)

I've removed the drivers multiple times, downloaded drivers using multiple sources, checked the BIOS, added the USB registry value. But I can't seem to find the solution.

The BIOS gives me these options for USB devices:

- Legacy USB Support: Enable/Disabled
- Legacy USB3 Support: Enable/Disabled
- EHCI Hand-off: Enable/Disabled

Looking at the image of the motherboard

[image: https://www.asus.com/media/global/products/Jfx0darRRdhhQ3So/P_setting_fff_1_90_end_500.png]

You can see that there's an extra case with 2 USB3 ports, which can be used as front panel USB ports. Those ports **do** work, but the ports on the back don't.

I'm running Windows 10, Creator Update.

Answer (score 0):

Your system has two identical XHCI controllers. If one has no problem and works but the other doesn't, there is no issue with software drivers. The problem seems to be in hardware of the second XHCI controller. The problem could be in faulty solder joints, or it could be in local firmware for the XHCI controller IC.

Renesas/NEC XCHI used to have an utility that upgrades IC firmware, which usually comes in a package with Windows driver. Try to obtain the original Renesas driver, it might fix the problem.

Alternatively, you can try any stand-alone Linux/Knoppix, or other stand-alone CD-based bootable OS (like Hieren's CD), to see if these systems can recognize both controllers and run them with no problems.

Comment: (If it's a hardware problem how does the other firmware help?)

Comment: @Ramhound, the controller seems to be partially alive, PCI config space is alive, so the EEPROM update channel might be still functional.